# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have imported geopandas and all the dependancies in my environment but I keep getting the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

Anyone knows why I keep getting this error? I'm using python 3.7 and Anaconda.

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to import the geopandas module? Is this being run from a script or in a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I'm using Spyder. Should I use another interpretor?

Comment: Are you sure you pip/conda installed geopandas within Anaconda?

Comment: @linus In just checked with "conda list" and Geopandas is there yes.

Comment: @AntP96 Have you activate the environment?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Yes the environment is activated.

Comment: To me this sounds like the IDE not using the environment you are expecting it to. However, I am not familiar enough with Spyder to help.

Comment: @speeder1987 Thanks for your help! I tried using Jupyter Notebook using the same environment and Geopandas is working.

Comment: see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder